# how to solve HDFC Bank missing orders in opencart

Tags: opencart, payment-gateway, opencart2.x

I have integrated the test kit of HDFC payment gateway in my website based on opencart.All orders from hdfc PG goes to missing orders even if I complete the orders.I want to know the reason behind it and whom should i reach out to.

Comment: Which API you're using, it would be great if you post your code & response which you get from bank payment gateway.

Comment: hi nipun,i have integrated the module of payu,i am getting sucess message whenever i place an order but on the portal, order goes to missing orders

Comment: what you're getting in response when payment will be done?